# Gradle - get URL of dependency artifact

Tags: gradle

I want to download the dependency artifacts manually in the future after Gradle has all the dependency artifacts available, hence I would like to get the URLs which Gradle used to download those artifacts.

Is there a way to get the URL of dependencies which artifacts have been downloaded by Gradle?

Comment: The two forum pages suggest that this is not possible yet.
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-you-find-the-source-url-for-a-dependency/13885
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-get-urls-for-dependencies/6349/2

Answer (score 8):

use gson for a example:

```
dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
}
```

create a task to print url:

```
task getURLofDependencyArtifact() {
    doFirst {
        project.configurations.compile.dependencies.each { dependency ->
            for (ArtifactRepository repository : project.repositories.asList()) {
                def url = repository.properties.get('url')
                //https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.6/gson-2.8.6.jar
                def jarUrl = String.format("%s%s/%s/%s/%s-%s.jar", url.toString(),
                        dependency.group.replace('.', '/'), dependency.name, dependency.version,
                        dependency.name, dependency.version)
                try {
                    def jarfile = new URL(jarUrl)
                    def inStream = jarfile.openStream();
                    if (inStream != null) {
                        println(String.format("%s:%s:%s", dependency.group, dependency.name, dependency.version)
                                + " -> " + jarUrl)
                        return
                    }
                } catch (Exception ignored) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

run `./gradlew getURLofDependencyArtifact`

> Task :getURLofDependencyArtifact
>
> com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6 -> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.6/gson-2.8.6.jar

PS:the result dependency your project's

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

so, the result maybe:

> Task :getURLofDependencyArtifact
>
> com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6 -> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.6/gson-2.8.6.jar

Comment: `dependency.group.replace` may fail if the group is null, so the `try` should be moved up before the `def jarUrl` line, IMO.

Comment: I am getting dependencies with URL as `.m2` local folder. Is there a way to get artifact URL instead of `.m2` location?

Comment: @AymanPatel Just filter out the mavenLocal repository from project.repositories.

Answer (score 7):

using Gradle version 6.0 or above, another way of outputting the URLs is to mix `--refresh-dependencies` with `--info`

```
// bash/terminal
./gradlew --info --refresh-dependencies
// cmd
gradlew --info --refresh-dependencies
```

or output to file

```
// bash/terminal
./gradlew --info --refresh-dependencies > urls.txt
// cmd
gradlew --info --refresh-dependencies > urls.txt
```

note on `--refresh-dependencies`

> It’s a common misconception to think that using --refresh-dependencies
> will force download of dependencies. This is not the case: Gradle will
> only perform what is strictly required to refresh the dynamic
> dependencies. This may involve downloading new listing or metadata
> files, or even artifacts, but if nothing changed, the impact is
> minimal.

source: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

see also: [How can I force gradle to redownload dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565082/how-can-i-force-gradle-to-redownload-dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

Wanted something similar but on Android and Kotlin DSL so based on @andforce's answer developed this which hopefully will be useful for others also,

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.utils.addToStdlib.firstNotNullResult
import java.net.URL

val dependenciesURLs: Sequence<Pair<String, URL?>>
    get() = project.configurations.getByName(
        "implementation"
    ).dependencies.asSequence().mapNotNull {
        it.run { "$group:$name:$version" } to project.repositories.mapNotNull { repo ->
            (repo as? UrlArtifactRepository)?.url
        }.flatMap { repoUrl ->
            "%s/%s/%s/%s/%s-%s".format(
                repoUrl.toString().trimEnd('/'),
                it.group?.replace('.', '/') ?: "", it.name, it.version,
                it.name, it.version
            ).let { x -> listOf("$x.jar", "$x.aar") }
        }.firstNotNullResult { url ->
            runCatching {
                val connection = URL(url).openConnection()
                connection.getInputStream() ?: throw Exception()
                connection.url
            }.getOrNull()
        }
    }
tasks.register("printDependenciesURLs") {
    doLast {
        dependenciesURLs.forEach { (dependency: String, url: URL?) -> println("$dependency => $url") }
    }
}
```

Update: It might not able to find indirect dependencies however.

Answer (score 0):

We need to take care about aar also.

```
 project.configurations.getByName(
                "implementation"
        ).dependencies.each { dependency ->
           
            for (ArtifactRepository repository : rootProject.repositories.asList()) {
                def url = repository.properties.get('url')
                def urlString = url.toString()
                if (url.toString().endsWith("/")) {
                    urlString = url.toString()
                } else {
                    urlString = url.toString() + "/"
                }
                def jarUrl = String.format("%s%s/%s/%s/%s-%s.jar", urlString,
                        dependency.group.replace('.', '/'), dependency.name, dependency.version,
                        dependency.name, dependency.version)

                def aarUrl = String.format("%s%s/%s/%s/%s-%s.aar", urlString,
                        dependency.group.replace('.', '/'), dependency.name, dependency.version,
                        dependency.name, dependency.version)
                try {
                    def jarfile = new URL(jarUrl)
                    def inStreamJar = jarfile.openStream();
                    if (inStreamJar != null) {
                        println(String.format("%s:%s:%s", dependency.group, dependency.name, dependency.version)
                                + " -> " + jarUrl)
                        return
                    }
                } catch (Exception ignored) {
                }

                try {
                    def aarfile = new URL(aarUrl).setURLStreamHandlerFactory()
                    def inStreamAar = aarfile.openStream();
                    if (inStreamAar != null) {
                        println(String.format("%s:%s:%s", dependency.group, dependency.name, dependency.version)
                                + " -> " + aarUrl)
                        return
                    }
                } catch (Exception ignored) {
                }
            }
        }
```