# Gradle: How can I resolve the URL to the latest version of the SNAPSHOT version in the Repository?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline

I'm building an app with Gradle. We're not currently versioning releases. (It's on the road-map.)
When *Deploying* releases into **UAT** or **PROD** with Jenkins,
It would be nice to automatically calculate the URL of the latest snapshot release in the Repository instead of having to pass in the file name.

How can I calculate the URL (to the filename) of the latest Snapshot when I have:

- Group
- Artifact ID
- Version

?

Comment: Isn't there also a `timestamp `included in the URL, making it almost impossible to calculate ?

Comment: look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697622/gradle-get-url-of-dependency-artifact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697622/gradle-get-url-of-dependency-artifact) from @Yuri G.
and the [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59457692/659354) from @lance-java about parsing the XML I was able to figure out a solution.

We're using gradle for the build, and I'm running this on Jenkins, I don't know if maven is installed.

I started with the Gradle Task from the link and then modified it to read the `maven-metadata.xml` file in the folder.  **NOTE:** we're using Artifactory not Nexus.

```
task getLatestSnapshotURL() {
        doLast
        {
           def url = artifactoryURL + config.binaryRepository.snapshotUrl

           def appBaseURL = String.format("%s/%s/%s/%s/", url.toString(),
                                          config.groupId.replace('.', '/'),
                                          config.artifactId, version)
                                  .replace('null','')

           def xmlUrl = appBaseURL + "maven-metadata.xml";
           println('metadata.xml URL: ' + xmlUrl)

           def ts = ''
           def build = ''

           try
           {
              def downloadXmlURL = new URL(xmlUrl)
              def fStream = downloadXmlURL.openStream()
              def slurper = new XmlSlurper().parse(fStream)
              println(slurper)
              println(XmlUtil.serialize(slurper))

              def ver = slurper.versioning
              println("versioning: " + ver)
              println(XmlUtil.serialize(ver))

              ts = ver.snapshot.timestamp.text()
              build = ver.snapshot.buildNumber.text()
           }
           catch(Exception ex)
           {
              println("Unexpected Error getting Snapshot Version "
                     + ex.getMessage() + "\n" + ex.getStackTrace());
           }

           println("ts: " + ts)
           println("ts Type: " + ts.getClass())
           println("build: " + build)
           println("build Type: " + build.getClass())

           def warUrl = appBaseURL + String.format("%s-%s-%s-%s.war",
                                                   config.artifactId,
                                                   version.replace("-SNAPSHOT", ''),
                                                   ts, build)
           println('war URL: ' + warUrl)

           try
           {
              def jarfile = new URL(warUrl)
              def inStream = jarfile.openStream();
              if (inStream != null)
              {
                 println(String.format("%s:%s:%s", config.groupId,
                                       config.artifactId, version)
                        + " -> " + warUrl)
                 return
              }
           }
           catch (Exception ignored) { }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using nexus, you can hit the URL "above" the jar url (ie the containing folder) which will return some xml which lists all the snapshots and their URLs. You can then parse the xml to get the latest.

There's also the [Nexus REST API](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api) which might allow you to get the path

There's also the [dependency:get](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html) plugin which allows you to download the latest snapshot by firing maven at command line (no pom.xml required).

Eg:

```
mvn dependency:get \
    -DrepoUrl=url \
    -Dartifact=groupId:artifactId:version
```